# Location not changed in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
search.directive('rootCategory', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
           controller: ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
                $scope.setUrl = function() {
                    var searchParams = {
                        'rootCategory': 'test'
                    };
                    $location
                        .path('/')
                        .search(searchParams);
                    console.log('Url changed');
                }
            }],
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function() {
                    $scope.setUrl();
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        }
    }
])
```

When i clicked on my element with this directive `<a data-root-category="">...</a>` a get info in my console: `Url changed`, but my url not change. why?

I also have a configuration for the location. Maybe that's the problem?

```
search.config(function ($interpolateProvider, $locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        reloadOnSearch: false
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The $location.search takes 2 parameters not an object

```
$scope.setUrl = function() {

                $location
                    .path('/')
                    .search('rootCategory', 'test');
                console.log('Url changed');
            }
```

EDIT: The docs are [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

But after a quick test it's possible just to use a string like

```
$scope.setUrl = function() {
                var searchParams = 'rootCategory=test';
                $location
                    .path('/')
                    .search(searchParams);
                console.log('Url changed');
            }
```